# Center Items in Bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 elements in a bootstrap row.  This can be easily solved just by giving each of the 3 items a class name `col-md-4` but this results in formatting issues.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container body-content">

  <form class="well form-inline" style="width: 100%;">

    <div class="row" style="margin:auto">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3" style="width: 31%;">
      <label class="control-label">Maintenance:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" cols="34" rows="10"></textarea>
      <label>250 characters left</label>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group col-md-3" style="width: 31%;">
      <label class="control-label">Operations:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" cols="34" rows="10"></textarea>
      <label>250 characters left</label>
   </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3" style="width: 31%;">
      <label class="control-label">Safety:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" cols="34" rows="10"></textarea>
      <label>250 characters left</label>
    </div>

  </div>


</form>

</div>
```

[Here is a bootply](http://www.bootply.com/FFORfYJFiP).

How do I correctly center these items?  I have tried margins but they really aren't getting my anywhere.

Comment: Add `.text-center` to each `.col-md-3`

Comment: That centers the label over top of the text areas but I am looking for the text areas to be centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit:***

You can use `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` on the parent container (that holds the 3 `.col-md-3`) to achieve exactly what you're after.

---

You can do this by simply adding `.text-center` to each of your `.col-md-3` elements. This will center all elements.

If you wish to center the text areas alone, you can do this:

`<div class="text-center"><textarea class="form-control" cols="34" rows="10"></textarea></div>`

Comment: I have updated my [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/vfnTeLO6K9) with your answer, but notice how there is much more room between the last text area from the side compared to the first text area?

Comment: Ahhh I see what you mean now. What formatting errors do you get using the col-md-4 classes? Another option is to override the parent container with `display: flex;` and then use the `justify-content: space-between`

Comment: The last text area's label will be displayed on the left side of the text-area.. due to length of other labels..

Comment: the override with flex and justify-content worked perfectly!

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Updated for you

Comment: Thank ya sir! Appreciated!

Comment: I just posted another question, maybe you could assist with that as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614516/align-labels-and-textboxes-in-form-inline

Comment: I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container body-content">

  <form class="well form-inline text-center" style="width: 100%;">



    <div class="row" style="margin:auto">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3" style="float:none">
      <label class="control-label">Maintenance:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" cols="34" rows="10"></textarea>
      <label>250 characters left</label>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group col-md-3" style="float:none">
      <label class="control-label">Operations:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" cols="34" rows="10"></textarea>
      <label>250 characters left</label>
   </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3" style="float:none">
      <label class="control-label">Safety:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" cols="34" rows="10"></textarea>
      <label>250 characters left</label>
    </div>

  </div>


</form>

</div>
```

Add text-center in parent container.
view it in full screen mode.

```
<form class="well form-inline text-center" style="width: 100%;">
```

Also col-md-3 has float:left with it. 
Adress this by adding style="float:none" on the div with col-md-3.

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-3" style="float:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set 100% width in all element means label, textarea. And change col-md-3 to col-md-4. Below is the code snipit.

```
    <div class="container body-content">

  <form class="well form-inline" style="width: 100%;">

    <div class="row" style="margin:auto">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
      <label class="control-label" style="width:100%;" >Maintenance:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control"  rows="10" style="width:100%;" ></textarea>
      <label style="width:100%;" >250 characters left</label>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group col-md-4"  >
      <label class="control-label" style="width:100%;">Operations:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control"  rows="10" style="width:100%;" ></textarea>
      <label style="width:100%;" >250 characters left</label>
   </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4"  >
      <label class="control-label" style="width:100%;">Safety:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" style="width:100%;" ></textarea>
      <label style="width:100%;" >250 characters left</label>
    </div>

  </div>


</form>

</div>
```

Comment: *"This can be easily solved just by giving each of the 3 items a class name col-md-4 but this results in formatting issues"*

Comment: There is no formatting issues when setting 100% width in label and textarea tag.

Comment: You don't know the full extent of the OPs planned usage. The fact they have already tried this and said what I quoted renders this a moot answer

Comment: but in my code there is no formatting issues. please check.

Comment: and if you want to center the text of label just use " .text-center " class in labeles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<div class="container">

  <form>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Maintenance:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" cols="34" rows="10"></textarea>
            <label>250 characters left</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Operations:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" cols="34" rows="10"></textarea>
            <label>250 characters left</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Safety:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" cols="34" rows="10"></textarea>
            <label>250 characters left</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

</div>
```

Here is the link. http://www.bootply.com/tvCIHTOdAE#