# Align Labels and Textboxes in Form-Inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap's grid system and want to create an inline form.

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="container body-content">

  <form class="well form-inline" style="width: 100%;">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Location:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>


        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Assignment:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Incident Number:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Date:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Training:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Example:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

</div>
```

When this is ran, there is no structure or alignment for the textboxes or the labels.  How can I achieve this?

[Here is a bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Uq5DSyAaGK)

Comment: Is [this](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/) what you used?

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#inline-forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each label and input you should make this structure:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
     <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Location:</label>
     <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
     </div> 
</div>
```

this will make it work with the grid system

[**See bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/7UBgZ8YkjC)

Comment: This works great, but I didn't include dropdownlists because I thought that this solution would be universal but it is not.. so I have updated my [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/97WY6Oq6Fe).. notice how one dropdownlist is wider than the other due to the placeholder length, even with the `col-md-8` specification? How do I get all dropdownlists to be the same width?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid, Select's `width` is set to `auto` in your normalize CSS. You need to set it to 100%. `select { width: 100%; }`. http://www.bootply.com/nA1v59YRTw

Comment: Thank ya sir! Appreciated!

Comment: Note that with this structure, the labels aren't vertically aligned with the inputs, as they normally are in Bootstrap forms. Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @inopinatus the float is what is causing the label to position on top, effected by the class col-lg..., one way to resolve the issue by removing the float .... see the link https://www.bootply.com/3yPhEMWptV

Comment: @chiller I eventually "cheated" and used .form-group { display:flex; align-items: center; }

Comment: @inopinatus flexbox is a life saver :) .. but be careful  for browser compatibility xD